# how to detect input value change without entering key value

Tags: html, angular

For instance:

```
 <input  class="table-input" type="number" name="qty" [(ngModel)]="cpy.qty" 
                  matInput min="1" max="{{cpy.qty}}"
```

where cpy is object. 
And cpy.qty is changing dynamically. Now I have to perform operation on onInputChange

How to detect dynamically inputchange Value?

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: u should see the input value changing

Comment: `cpy` can't be an array.It may be an Object, but not an array in that case. Can you please provide the expected behavior? It's unclear.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically changed value, you can handle change logic with ngDoCheck https://angular.io/api/core/DoCheck

Comment: then use ngDoCheck

Comment: ngDoCheck  is also not detecting dynamically value change.

Comment: Can you display your code. Because in my case it is not working

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-baj4bd?file=src/app/app.component.ts